# Rendering XML data in GWT application

Tags: gwt, xml-parsing

I have an XML object which comes as the response from a web service. I obtain the XML data using

> `Document xmlDoc = XMLParser.parse( response )`;

What is the easier and better way to render the `xmlDoc` in my `DialogBox` widget?

**EDIT**

Am having an XML object. I want to render the data inside a panel and show it on the GUI. Hope this helps.

To put in a better way,

Is it possible to directly add XML document to a panel in GWT, or we should parse the same and build the panel ourselves?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? what do you want? Do you want to layout xml as node structure in DialogBox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to parse the web service response

```
Document messageDom = XMLParser.parse( response );
```

Then, you can get the node value by

```
String nodeValue = "";
final NodeList nlist = messageDom.getElementsByTagName( tagName );
if (nlist == null || nlist.getLength() <= 0) 
    nodeValue = "";
else 
    nodeValue = nlist.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
```

from here, you can now set panel component value to `nodeValue`